# SQL cluster vs single server

Tags: sql-server

If a database from a single server environment is copied to a sql cluster environment, would one expect SQL query times to be faster, slower or about the same from the cluster environment?

Assumptions:

SQL Server 2005

Hardware specs are the same.

Thanks,
Dwight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should see about the same query times, as the SQL database is only running on a single node of the (failover-) cluster at any given time. Clustering for performance is done by using many nodes and load balancing several SQL Server instances across several nodes for redundancy and improved performance.

Answer (score 1):

Clustering is a High Availability feature. It has absolutely no impact on performance. You're only going to utilize one node of the cluster at any time for your load. So the new database will behave slower, faster, or about the same, depending on the hardware capabilities of the active node and other concurrent load on this node, compared with the single server environment.